# Failed to extract body due to: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from byte(Failed to extract sent Zip file to ActiveMQ)

Tags: c#, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, nms

I am trying to send message to ActiveMQ server with my client app written on C# .NET. I have XML messages which I have converted into Zip stream and trying to send.

```
public IMessage SendMessage(string mqUri, string brokerUri, MemoryStream message, string username, string password)
    {
        Uri connecturi = new Uri(mqUri);

        IConnectionFactory factory = new NMSConnectionFactory(connecturi);

        using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection(username, password))
        using (ISession session = connection.CreateSession())
        {
            IDestination destination = SessionUtil.GetDestination(session, brokerUri);

            using (IMessageProducer producer = session.CreateProducer(destination))
            {
                connection.Start();
                IBytesMessage request = session.CreateBytesMessage(message.ToArray());
                producer.Send(request);

                return request;
            }
        }
    }
```

On server side when parsing data got exception like:

Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - Failed to extract body due to: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from bytes. Reason: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00010000. Message: ActiveMQObjectMessage.

When I debug the code and set break point, there is exception on Bodylength and content saying *'request.Content' threw an exception of type 'Apache.NMS.MessageNotReadableException'*

[image]

Is there any special zip conversion to send message on ActiveMQ server? Please Help. Thanks

Comment: why converting an xml to zip ?? can you open the zip file with any zip tools ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was converting zip to *memorystream*, Later I found it needs to convert .xml file to *zipstream* not the zip file.

```
public static MemoryStream CreateZipStream()
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
            outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string filePath =
                @"C:\YourXml.xml";
            zip.AddFile(filePath);
            zip.Save(outputStream);
            return outputStream;
        }
    }
```